# mysql Join showing wrong result PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have following three tables:

**taxi:**

```
id          shopid      taxiId      status
1           20          1               1
2           20          2               1               
3           20          3               2
4           20          4               1
5           21          1               1
...
```

**preBooking:**

```
id      shopid          taxiId          status
1       20              1               booked
2       20              3               booked
```

**usrBooking:**

```
id      shopid          taxiId          status
1       20              2               booked
2       20              4               booked
```

Now I want to get all records from `taxi` table ( for example shop id=20), and matching record of `preBooking` and `usrBooking` table.

For example I want to get records like this (if i pass shop id 20 in parameter)

```
id          shopid      taxiId      preBookingstatus        usrBookingstatus
1           20          1               Booked              Null
2           20          2               Null                Booked
3           20          3               Booked              Null
4           20          4               Null                Booked
```

I tried with following code but not working correctly,showing wrong results

```
$shopid="20";
$this->db->select('t.taxiId,ub.status as usrBookingstatus ,pb.status as preBookingstatus ');
$this->db->from('taxi t');
$this->db->join('usrBooking ub', 'ub.taxiId=t.taxiId','LEFT OUTER');
$this->db->join('preBooking pb', 'pb.taxiId=t.taxiId','LEFT OUTER');
$this->db->where('t.shopid', $shopid);
$this->db->order_by('t.taxiId', 'ASC');
```

Comment: can you share the results you received from the current query

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your select statement is missing a few columns. Change

```
$this->db->select('t.taxiId,ub.status as usrBookingstatus ,pb.status as preBookingstatus ');
```

to

```
$shopid=20;
$this->db->select('t.id, t.shopid, t.taxiId,pb.status as preBookingstatus , ub.status as usrBookingstatus ');
$this->db->from('taxi as t');
$this->db->join('usrBooking as ub', 't.taxiId=ub.taxiId','LEFT');
$this->db->join('preBooking as pb', 't.taxiId=pb.taxiId','LEFT');
$this->db->where('t.shopid', $shopid);
$this->db->order_by('t.taxiId', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

First I am unsure what is this:

```
$this->db->where('c.salon_id', $shopid);
```

There is no table "c" in the FROM of the query and "salon_id" is not mentioned in the example data above. This makes the query invalid and you can't run it. Maybe this is the issue. Probably you should change it to:

```
$this->db->where('t.shopid', $shopid);
```

Also you are missing some columns in the SELECT. The full query should be:

```
SELECT t.id, t.shopid, t.taxiId, pb.status as preBookingstatus, ub.status as usrBookingstatus
FROM taxi t
LEFT JOIN usrBooking ub ON ub.taxiId=t.taxiId
LEFT JOIN preBooking pb ON pb.taxiId=t.taxiId
WHERE t.shopid = 20
ORDER BY t.taxiId ASC;
```

Or with your PHP code:

```
$shopid="20";
$this->db->select('t.id, t.shopid, t.taxiId, pb.status as preBookingstatus, ub.status as usrBookingstatus');
$this->db->from('taxi t');
$this->db->join('usrBooking ub', 'ub.taxiId=t.taxiId','LEFT OUTER');
$this->db->join('preBooking pb', 'pb.taxiId=t.taxiId','LEFT OUTER');
$this->db->where('t.shopid', $shopid);
$this->db->order_by('t.taxiId', 'ASC');
```

Comment: There is still no table "c" in the FROM. It should be "t.shopid".

Comment: So... is there still a problem?